# Dynamically create panels in Streamlit?

Tags: streamlit

I have a list of data which may change from time to time.

The feature I have in mind looks like a carousel:

[image]

The closest layout I can find in Streamlit is the [columns](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.columns) layout.  But the problem is that the number of panels must be known beforehand.

Is there a way to get the columns but in a dynamically generated fashion? I understand the other issue I will have is the scrollibility of the page once there are many panels.